# How to fix the hresult e_fail error of a call to a com component?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I got this error when wanting to add a reference, could you help me, I know that this problem is very general but if you have the solution could you help me? This error arises in the visual studio 2017[image]

regards!

Answer (score 0):

finally , I found the answer in this link:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/260196/add-a-reference-raise-error-error-hresult-e-fail-h.html

## 1 Open "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" as Admin

## 2 CD into "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies"

## 3 Run "gacutil -i Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.11.0.dll"

## After a restart, it all worked well.